# Apple Touch Bar Favourites Icon for Website Not Working

Tags: html, macos, svg, macbookpro-touch-bar

So I'm building a website and I can't get the svg icon to show up correctly on my MacBook's Touch Bar when I add the site to my favourites list.

The webpage in question can be found here: http://japesfawcett.com

I have an SVG file that is a black thunderbolt on a white background, and I am using the following code for the Touch Bar icon:

```
<link rel="mask-icon" href="img/favicon.svg" color="#000000">
```

The code of the SVG is as follows:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
        .st0{fill:#231F20;}
    </style>
    <path class="st0" d="M41.3,45.9c2.4,1.6,4.6,0.3,7.4,0.1c-1.7,3.4-3.3,6.5-4.8,9.6c-0.6,1.3-0.9,2.8-1.5,4.1  c-0.6,1.3-1.4,2.5-1.9,3.8c-2.2,5.2-4,10.6-6.6,15.5c-2,3.7-2.7,7.6-4.4,11.6c0.9,0.5,1.8,0.9,2.9,1.4c4.6-6.2,9.2-12.3,13.7-18.5  c4.8-6.4,8.3-13.5,11.9-20.6c1.6-3.2,4.1-6.1,6.4-8.9c2.6-3.2,5.4-6.1,6.2-10.3c-4-2.7-8.7-1.7-13.3-2c2.2-6.7,4.2-13.1,6.3-19.6  c0.5-1.4,1-2.8-0.6-4.1c-4.4,1.1-6.1,5-8.1,8.4c-2.7,4.6-5,9.4-7.5,14.1c-1,1.8-2.1,3.4-3.1,5.2C42.5,38.7,41.3,42,41.3,45.9z"/>
</svg>
```

For some reason the Touch Bar icon for the site is appearing all white with no image visible in it. I can't get the SVG to be visible at all!

If anyone has any insights as to how to fix this it'd be greatly appreciated, it's been driving me mad!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that the problem lies in your SVG, which is **incorrectly cropped** (it's outside the 16x16 pixel bounds defined by the `viewBox`). Replace the path in it with the following:

```
<path class="st0" d="M2.29683698,7.21904762 C2.76399027,7.52380952 3.19221411,7.27619048 3.73722628,7.23809524 C3.40632603,7.88571429 3.09489051,8.47619048 2.80291971,9.06666667 C2.68613139,9.31428571 2.62773723,9.6 2.51094891,9.84761905 C2.39416058,10.0952381 2.23844282,10.3238095 2.14111922,10.5714286 C1.71289538,11.5619048 1.36253041,12.5904762 0.856447689,13.5238095 C0.467153285,14.2285714 0.330900243,14.9714286 0,15.7333333 C0.175182482,15.8285714 0.350364964,15.9047619 0.564476886,16 C1.45985401,14.8190476 2.35523114,13.6571429 3.23114355,12.4761905 C4.16545012,11.2571429 4.84671533,9.9047619 5.54744526,8.55238095 C5.85888078,7.94285714 6.34549878,7.39047619 6.79318735,6.85714286 C7.29927007,6.24761905 7.84428224,5.6952381 8,4.8952381 C7.22141119,4.38095238 6.30656934,4.57142857 5.41119221,4.51428571 C5.83941606,3.23809524 6.22871046,2.01904762 6.63746959,0.780952381 C6.73479319,0.514285714 6.83211679,0.247619048 6.52068127,0 C5.66423358,0.20952381 5.33333333,0.952380952 4.94403893,1.6 C4.41849148,2.47619048 3.97080292,3.39047619 3.48418491,4.28571429 C3.28953771,4.62857143 3.07542579,4.93333333 2.88077859,5.27619048 C2.53041363,5.84761905 2.29683698,6.47619048 2.29683698,7.21904762 Z"></path>
```

Also, [the icon should be completely black](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40960861/3151675), so you should change the `fill` property of the `st0` class:

```
.st0{fill:#000;}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion! However, it still doesn't seem to be making a difference.